# Is it possible to have more than two Floating Action Buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm struggling with something that should be pretty straight-forward, and now I don't know if it is some undocumented limitation of the FAB element. I have three identical FABs in one screen inside an horizontal `LinearLayout`, but the third one doesn't show its icon.

[image]

Here's the code for that:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/gallery_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
            app:backgroundTint="#FF5252"
            app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/camera_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
            app:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
            app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/text_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
            app:backgroundTint="#21BFF3"
            app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Even more, if I add an additional one to the `LinearLayout`, the result is exactly the same, the fourth one not appearing at all. Is there some kind of limitations for the number of FABs to show? I'm not manipulating the FABs by code in any way, only adding a click listener to each of them. The icons are vector drawables directly imported from the Material icons library (and for the sake of this example, I put the same one for the three of them).

I'm not sure what the specific problem might be, but it is giving me a headache...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `width` and `height` to 80dp too

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/gallery_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF5252"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/text_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_btn_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#21BFF3"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the end the problem was not this linear layout, but the view containing it... but your suggestion put me in the right track!